# Trigger a function by scrolling up

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scale

I want to scale a `DIV` with some content by scrolling the mousewheel. Scrolling up should result in scaling up and scrolling down in scaling down. So I know it's possible because you can detect the deltaY and could trigger a function. So I need to know how to make it. Here's my attempt.

```js
function scale(event) {
     var y = event.deltaY;
     if (y > 0) {
       document.getElementById('scalediv').style.transform = scale(1);
     }
   }
```

```css
#scalediv {
  transform: scale(0.4)
 }
```

```html
<div id="scalediv">
Lorem
</div>
```

Comment: 1. You need to set the function as event listener: `scalediv.onmousewheel = scale;` 2. you need `....transform = "scale(" + y / 500 + ")"` or something like that

Comment: Thanks. Helped for sure. But... Is it possible to detect if the mouse wheel got scrolled up rather than just being scrolled? That would help alot!

Comment: `event.deltaY` will be positive or negative, depending on the direction: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/ksgc1d9j/

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped a lot. I think the case is closed now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried binding wheel on the div itself?

```
document.getElementById("scalediv").addEventListener("wheel", resize);

function resize(event){
  console.log(event);
}
```

then look if event.deltaY is negative or positive :-)

simple solution without boundries (min and max value), I belive you can figure this simple if by yourself

```
<div id="scalediv" style="transform: scale(0.4)">
   Lorem
</div>
```

-

```
document.getElementById("scalediv").addEventListener("wheel", resize);

function resize(event) {
  console.log(event);
  var scaledDiv = document.getElementById("scalediv").style.transform;
  var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var scaleValue = regExp.exec(scaledDiv);
  var valueAsNumber = Number(scaleValue[1]);
  var newValue = valueAsNumber + 0.1;
  if (event.deltaY > 0) {
    newValue = valueAsNumber - 0.1;
  }
  document
    .getElementById("scalediv")
    .setAttribute("style", "transform: scale(" + newValue + ")");
}
```

Comment: Could you help me with that? Or give me some clues. As i said i want to learn and can't find anything online.

Comment: @OKGoogle posted solution, its not perfect but works, it needs boundries (min and max values) and ofcourse some sort of debounce/throttle (to slow down the scroll)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to Lukas's answer, but I believe my code to be a bit more straight forward and readable. I'm also using [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) here to keep the setting and getting of the current scale size cleaner and slightly more performant.

```
const div = document.querySelector('div')
const scaleVariable = '--scale-size'

window.addEventListener('wheel', scrollHandler, {
  passive: true
})

function scrollHandler (e) {
  // Find out which direction we scrolled in:
  var dir = Math.sign(e.deltaY)

  // Since dir can sometimes be -0 or 0, exclude those scenarios with this if clause
  if (dir) {
    // Get the existing CSS custom property
    const currentSize = div.style.getPropertyValue(scaleVariable)
    // Modify it in the direction of the scroll
    let newSize = parseFloat(currentSize || 1, 10) + dir * 0.1
    // Set size boundaries
    if (newSize < 0.3) newSize = 0.3
    else if (newSize > 5) newSize = 5
    // Set the new size through the property
    if (newSize) div.style.setProperty(scaleVariable, newSize.toFixed(2))
  }
}
```

You can see a live demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/andreasvirkus/m5w38sz9/2/

From the CSS, only this part is relevant (the rest is just styles for demo purposes):

```
div {
  --scale-size: 1;
  transform: scale(var(--scale-size));
}
```

Lastly, if this was production-level code, I'd suggest you [throttle](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-646d076d0a44) the `wheel` listener